# Activate atime for a specific directory

Tags: webserver

I know that by changing something in 'etc/fstab' I can activate atime for every file in the system. But what I need, or rather want, is to activate it for a specific directory, say 'var/www/vhosts/myfiles'. Is it possible? What would I need to add to the fstab file in order to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. You only **disable** atime for specific items, not enable it.

So maybe, if your /var/www is on a separate partition, you can enable atime (in fstab) for everything on this mountpoint, then recursively disable atime for every root folder of this mountpoint minus 'var/www/vhosts/myfiles' using:

```
chattr -R +A /path/to/your/folder
```

the '+A' is the 'disable atime' attribute.

But it can only be a real alternative if there is not too many changes inside your FS directories / files (newly created items won't have the 'disable atime' attribute set.

Sorry for not being able to help more, but I really think it's a system limitation.

Note that on recent kernel versions, you can use the mount option 'relatime' (it is even the default I think), which still updates atime but far less often, so you don't notice the performance impact of it.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by forcing every user who opens a file go through a PHP script first, and there I call the touch() function.

Comment: Yes, that's a very good compromise.